# Claves primarias compuestas

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Alguien de buen corazon que podria darme una explicación coherente de que son y por qué se debería usar claves compuestas en una sola tabla, una tabla sin PK propia de la tabla, si no que con dos(2) PKs que son propias de otras tablas. Acudo a ese sitio ya que ningún docente me pudo ejemplificar la necesidad lógica para usar y, en internet solo encuentro ejemplos de poco contenido.
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Contanos que encontraste y entendiste.. asi te explicamos lo que te falta!

Comment: cuando un solo atributo no es suficiente para identificar unequivocamente a una entidad, se necesitan 2. ejempĺo : matriculaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que describes me parece que estas hablando de una relación de muchos a muchos, [Muchos a Muchos](https://www.aulapc.es/lupa_busquedas_posit.html1accesF%7EF4.00). Para que un registro sea univoco debe tener alguna manera de identificarlo, ¿cómo sabemos que el registro "pepe martinez" de la tabla personas es único? pues se busca una propiedad que lo identifique, por ejemplo en ese caso podríamos agregar un campo de identificación como documento de identidad "DI" que sería la clave de esa tabla:

```
DI | Nombre | Apellido
222| Pepe   | Martinez
333| Pepe   | Martinez
```

Aunque los nombres y apellidos se repitan, para el modelo son dos distintos ya su clave difiere (su **primary key** es **ID**), lo que en realidad está bien porque muchas personas se llaman igual que otras, así que en este caso el modelo es válido.

Ahora supongamos que en este modelo de datos las personas pueden tener autos, de hecho pueden tener muuuchos autos, tenemos una relación de uno a muchos (una entidad puede estar relacionada muchas veces con otra), para facilitar dejaremos la tabla con dos nombres distintos:

```
DI | Nombre | Apellido
222| Pepe   | Martinez
333| María  | Martinez
```

Y agregaremos la entidad autos, teniendo en cuenta que un auto tiene color, modelo y año, dejaremos como identificar un número de serial:

```
Serial| Color | Modelo      | Año
444   | Negro | Ford Fiesta | 2010
555   | Verde | Fiar Kwid   | 2021
```

El problema ahora es ¿cómo se deja reflejada en las tablas la relación que indicamos con anterioridad (una persona tiene muchos autos)?, si vemos los datos de la tabla personas no nos dice que Pepe está relacionado con algún auto, de igual manera en la tabla autos con respecto a personas. La respuesta es que podríamos dejar en la tabla personas el identificador del auto:

```
DI | Nombre | Apellido | Serial_Auto
222| Pepe   | Martinez | 444
333| María  | Martinez | 555
```

Ah hermoso!, Pepe está relacionado con el auto 444 (Ford fiesta negro) y María con el auto 555 (Fiat Kwid verder). Serial_Auto es una **foreign key** ya que esa columna almacena la **primary key** del registro con el que se relaciona. Verás que muchas veces por convención el campo se le agrega fk_ al principio quedando fk_serial_auto o fk_auto_serial, lo que suene mejor, incluso a veces solo dejan el nombre del campo, fk_serial.

Pero... y si queremos que Pepe también sea dueño del auto Fiat verde?, o al contrario para María?, pues podríamos decir que bueno repetimos la información de la tabla para Pepe y agregamos el otro id:

```
DI | Nombre | Apellido | Serial_Auto
222| Pepe   | Martinez | 444
222| Pepe   | Martinez | 555
333| María  | Martinez | 555
```

Vale, acá tenemos dos problemas, el primero es que estamos violando la restricción de la **primary key** ID, no pueden haber dos registros con el mismo valor de la columna ID en la tabla personas, si cambiamos el id del segundo Pepe pues ya no es el mismo Pepe... Si hablamos de María sería el mismo caso. El segundo problema es que estamos repitiendo la información, cosa que en las bases de datos relacionales se busca eliminar, para eso existen técnicas de normalización que nos permiten crear modelos que tengan el menor número de datos repetidos (pero eso es otra historia).

Asi que ¿cómo resolvemos éste problema?, pues de nuevo, podríamos decir que entonces ya que no puedo colocar la clave de Autos en Personas, pues hagámoslo al revés, en Autos coloquemos el ID de Personas... Entonces si Fiat tiene de dueño a Pepe quedaría:

```
Serial| Color | Modelo      | Año  | ID_Persona
444   | Negro | Ford Fiesta | 2010 | 222
555   | Verde | Fiar Kwid   | 2021 | 333
```

Bien (nótese que María quedó como dueña de Kwid), pero si auto verde también está relacionado con Pepe tendríamos el mismo problema, ya que repetimos el Serial (cosa que viola la primary key) y repetimos información:

```
Serial| Color | Modelo      | Año  | ID_Persona
444   | Negro | Ford Fiesta | 2010 | 222
444   | Negro | Ford Fiesta | 2010 | 333
555   | Verde | Fiar Kwid   | 2021 | 333
```

Pues si no se puede colocar la clave primaria en ninguna tabla cómo se puede lograr almacenar esa relación??. Primero notar que la relación que estamos queriendo reflejar es muchos a muchos, porque un auto puede tener **muchos** dueños y una persona puede ser dueña de **muchos** autos (ambas aserciones indican **muchos**, de allí el nombre del tipo de relación). Entonces para resolver este conflicto lo que se debe hacer es crear una tabla aparte que almacene solo las claves primarias de ambas tablas en la relación:

```
Serial_Auto | ID_Persona
444         | 222
```

Genial, el auto 444 tiene como dueño a la persona 222, si queremos que el auto 444 tenga como dueño a la persona 333 simplemente agregamos otro registro:

```
Serial_Auto | ID_Persona
444         | 222
444         | 333
```

En cualquier momento que se necesite saber quién es dueño de cual auto simplemente hay que ir a esta tabla (que se puede llamar Autos_Personas) y ver la información de las claves foreaneas, porque Serial_Auto y ID_Persona son claves foreaneas en esta tabla Autos_Personas. De hecho no pasa nada si vemos ésta tabla como Personas_Autos, si tiene más sentido verlo así pues se vale:

```
ID_Persona | Serial_Auto
222        | 444
333        | 444
```

La razón por la que te dicen que una tabla tiene que tener como clave compuesta dos primary keys propias de otras tablas, es que en la tabla Personas_Auto también tiene que tener su manera de identificar cada registro (cada relación entre personas y autos) de manera univoca, si en esta tabla Personas_Auto colocamos solo como primary el campo ID_Persona no podemos tener más de una relación entre una persona y un auto, lo siguiente violaría la restricción de la clave primaria:

```
ID_Persona | Serial_Auto
222        | 444
222        | 555
333        | 444
```

Acá el manejador de base de datos diría que el registro con el ID 222 ya se encuentra al intentar agregar el registro con el serial_auto 555. Si se coloca como clave el campo Serial_Auto pues ya está violando ésa restricción porque se repite 444 para el registro con la persona 333.

La solución es indicar que en ésta tabla la manera de identificar univocamente un registro es con ambas columnas (una clave compuesta), ID_Persona y Serial_Auto en conjunto hacen que no se repitan los registros, es decir podemos agregar muchas personas (que el valor de ID_Persona se pueda repetir) y que podemos agregar muchos autos (que el valor de Serial_Auto se pueda repetir) peeero que no se pueda repetir la misma combinación de ID_Persona y Serial_Auto, por lo que esto estaría bien bajo este contexto (clave compuesta):

```
ID_Persona | Serial_Auto
222        | 444
222        | 555
333        | 444
333        | 555
```

Pero lo siguiente este mal:

```
ID_Persona | Serial_Auto
222        | 444
222        | 555
222        | 555
333        | 444
333        | 555
```

Al intentar repetir la relación de la Persona 222 con el Auto 555 el motor de base de datos indicaría error ya que se repite la clave primaria (compuesta) de esa tabla.

Respuesta corta, porque en las relaciones de muchos a muchos para poder almacenarlas correctamente se crea una nueva entidad que tenga las claves de las dos entidades a relacionar y la clave primaria de esa nueva entidad será una clave compuesta entre las claves foráneas de las entidades relacionadas.

Comment: Gracias por contestar.

Comment: @Paco En este sitio agradecemos las respuestas válidas **aceptándolas**. Así la comunidad puede ver que la pregunta ya fue respuesta satisfactoriamente. Te dejo [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) donde explican como aceptar respuestas válidas y este [otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) donde explican porque es importante la aceptación de respuestas correctas. Gracias por colaborar en el buen funcionamiento de este sitio.

Comment: Listo, gracias.